# Move folder outside of project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I need to change the build folder destination of my android project. Currently, build folder is located inside project.
I would like to move build folder outside of project.
I use this code but this path is relative, not absolute.

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "~/Library/Android/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I use this code but this path is relative, not absolute" -- what happens when you use an absolute path?

Comment: Nothing happens. Build folder is not created.